# Hazelcast IMap LRU Eviction Policy always evicting the latest entry

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We were exploring the different eviction policy options and found out that the LRU Eviction policy is evicting the newly added entry instead of Least Recently Used entry. It behaves the same way for LFU option as well.

Ideally, the first entry should get evicted first before the second or third gets evicted.

**Is this a bug in Hazelcast or am I missing any option/configuration?**

Hazelcast Version - 3.6.2

Here is the code sample to replicate the issue(Run with -Xmx512m):

```
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.EvictionPolicy;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizeConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.EntryEvent;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.map.listener.EntryEvictedListener;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class HazelcastMaxSizeTest {

    private static final String GROUP_NAME = "TEST";
    private static final String MAP_NAME = "test";
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, byte[]> theDataMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, byte[]>();


    private static MaxSizeConfig USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE = new MaxSizeConfig(5, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE);
    private static MaxSizeConfig USED_HEAP_SIZE = new MaxSizeConfig(128, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE);
    private static MaxSizeConfig FREE_HEAP_SIZE = new MaxSizeConfig(128, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE);
    private static MaxSizeConfig FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE = new MaxSizeConfig(30, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        boolean storeOutSideHazelcast = true;
        HazelcastInstance instance = startHazelcast("hazelcast1", FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE);
        System.out.println("started " + instance.getName());

        IMap<Long, byte[]> map = createMap(instance, MAP_NAME, storeOutSideHazelcast);
        System.out.println("map size: " + map.size());

        instance.shutdown();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static HazelcastInstance startHazelcast(String instanceName, MaxSizeConfig maxSizeConfig) {

        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig(MAP_NAME);
        mapConfig.setMaxSizeConfig(maxSizeConfig);
        mapConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
        mapConfig.setEvictionPercentage(10);
        mapConfig.setMinEvictionCheckMillis(0L);
        mapConfig.setBackupCount(0);
        mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(600);

        Config config = new Config(instanceName);
        config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
        config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
        config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter-3.6.2.war");
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(GROUP_NAME).setPassword(GROUP_NAME);
        return Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    private static IMap<Long, byte[]> createMap(HazelcastInstance instance,
                                                String mapname
                , boolean storeOutsideHZMap ) {

        IMap<Long, byte[]> map = instance.getMap(mapname);

        map.addEntryListener(new EntryEvictedListener<Long, byte[]>() {

            @Override
            public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<Long, byte[]> event) {
                System.out.println("Evicted Key" + ": " + event.getKey());
                theDataMap.remove(event.getKey());
            }

        }, false);

        for (long i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {

            if(storeOutsideHZMap == true) {
                theDataMap.put(i, new byte[50 * 50000]);
                map.set(i, new byte[10]);
                System.out.println("Adding Key " + ": " + i);
                map.get(i);
            }else {
                map.set(i, new byte[50*50000]);
            }

            if (i % 100 == 0) {
//                System.out.println("set " + map.getName() + ": " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000l);
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

Sample Output:

```
Adding Key : 147
Evicted Key: 147
Adding Key : 148
Evicted Key: 148
Adding Key : 149
Evicted Key: 149
Adding Key : 150
Evicted Key: 150
Adding Key : 151
Evicted Key: 151
Adding Key : 152
Evicted Key: 152
Adding Key : 153
Evicted Key: 153
Adding Key : 154
Evicted Key: 154
Adding Key : 155
Evicted Key: 155
Adding Key : 156
Evicted Key: 156
Adding Key : 157
Evicted Key: 157
```